# ASPNetCore Web API integration tests using Test Host or WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit.net

I am writing Integration Test for an ASPNetCore web API project. While reading about it I came across two terminologies, first is

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing.WebApplicationFactory`

and second is

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`

References:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1
2. https://koukia.ca/integration-testing-in-asp-net-core-2-0-51d14ede3968

I am a little confused, why and which kind of setup I should use to test Web API controllers?

Comment: I have same question, have you figured it out?

Comment: @kvuong Yes, I am following an older approach (TestHost) because I had my startup class in another assembly (internal) and I had been exposing 
**IWebHostBuilder** to my API project. So, in that case, I could not able to use **WebApplicationFactory** which takes **Startup.cs class**. And as I have IWebHostBuilder reference I could directly use **TestServer(IWebHostBuilder)** to create the test client.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I believe, the former mate is the replacement approach to the latter. This is according to the latest blogs from MightySoft.

Answer (score 3):

**I am following an older approach (TestHost)**

because I had my startup class in another assembly (internal) and I had been exposing `IWebHostBuilder` to my API project.
So, in that case, I could not able to use `WebApplicationFactory` which takes `Startup.cs` class. And as I have an `IWebHostBuilder` reference I could directly use `TestServer(IWebHostBuilder)` to create the test client.